# xamarin froms parse JSON from django rest framework

Tags: django, parsing, xamarin

I can successfully register with my xamarin forms app in django website and if username or email already exist i receive http response from django rest framework in this format :

```
{
"username": [
    "account with this username already exists."
],
"email": [
    "account with this email already exists."
]
```

}

i want to show these errors in display alert without username and email. only text of error ( for example: account with this username already exists or account with this email already exists) i've tried to parse it in a lot of ways but none of them worked. how can i achieve it?

code in my app:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "username", EntryUsername.Text },
            { "email", EntryEmail.Text },
            { "password", EntryPassword1.Text },
            { "password2", EntryPassword2.Text }
        };

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

        var response = await client.PostAsync("http://192.168.0.101:8000/api/account/register", content);

        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using [Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

```
var data = "{\"username\": [\"account with this username already exists.\"],\"email\": [\"account with this email already exists.\"]}";

var obj = JObject.Parse(data);
    
Console.WriteLine(obj["username"][0]);
Console.WriteLine(obj["email"][0]);
```

Comment: if only username or email is incorrect i got one message in response and another message is null. and in this case i have this exception: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' how can i avoid it?

Comment: test for `obj["username"] == null`